# Create custom RxJs Subject

Tags: rxjs

## Question

Is there an official recommended way to create a custom RxJs Subject?

## Use Case

I have a need for a `QueueSubject`, i.e. a Subject that queues all values passed to its `next` method until there is a subscriber. This is different from the built-in [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) because the ReplaySubject does not clear its buffer upon a subscription.

## What I have learned so far

An exact implementation of what I need is available in [this GitHub project by James Pike](https://github.com/ohjames/queueing-subject/blob/master/src/index.ts). The reason for my question despite this perfectly available solution is that the `_subscribe` method is an internal method. It is even marked as `@deprecated`, therefore if a linter is used, a linter rule exception needs to be added to the class to suppress the deprecation warning.

I did not find anything in the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md) about how to create a custom Subject.

Comment: You should call `subscribe()` and not `_subscribe()`. `QueueingSubject` inherits `Subject` so it has `subscribe` like any Observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any `Subject` implementation as a reference for your own custom one, for example [this one on Github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts).

Concerning `_subscribe`: You can override it with your custom class, but never call it directly from an outside consumer class (this is why it is annotated with `@deprecated`). The function is called by the `Subject` class internally following the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

In summary: Your linked implementation looks valid to me.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/samherrmann/a787bb623799e85df531786568136bad) is the alternative implementation that I just put together using the `subscribe` method instead of the `_subscribe` method as Martin suggested in his comment. From what I can see, both approaches work the same but `_subscribe` is a couple of lines less code. Do you know if there's a functional difference that I am overlooking between the two approaches?

Comment: There is a difference if you look at the implementation of `_subscribe` in Subject. You have an instance of `Subscriber`, which has a different API than e.g. a `next` function that is passed to `subscribe`. This gives you a bit more control on how to handle subscriptions.